# Updating entity framework entity with many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have (2) entities, they are as follows:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Roles = new Collection<Role>();
    }
}


[Table("User")]
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new Collection<User>();
    }
}
```

This creates three tables in my database, User, Role and UserRole.

I am leveraging a generic repository, my Add and Update look like the following:

```
    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

If I want to add a new User with Roles, I have to do the following in my UserRepository, which inherits from my generic repository.

```
    public override void Add(User entity)
    {
        foreach (var role in entity.Roles)
            _dbContext.Roles.Attach(role);

        base.Add(entity);
    }
```

This seems clunky, but it works.

My trouble is now when I want to update a User, say add a new Role. I thought I could do something similar.

```
    public override void Update(User entity)
    {
        foreach (var role in entity.Roles)
            _dbContext.Roles.Attach(role);

        base.Update(entity);
    }
```

But this does not work ... any ideas on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated!

**Update**

My use case is I have an existing User with X Roles, I add Y number of Roles, I want to update the User with the Y number of new Roles.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do that.  If the role does not yet exist, you would do something like this:

```
var user = new User { Name="Fred" }
user.Roles.Add(new Role { Name="Accounting" });

context.Add(user);
```

If you are adding an existing role, then you need to get that role first

```
var role = context.Roles.Single(x => x.Name="Accounting");

var user = new User { Name="Fred" }
user.Roles.Add(role);

context.Add(user);
```

Comment: Let's assume my User already exists and has (4) roles, (2) of which are new. All roles are pre-existing.

Comment: Then you just get the two new roles from the Roles DbSet, get the user, add the roles to the user via Roles.Add, then save changes.

Comment: I guess where I am getting confused is the fact that I am working with a detached object, and I need to hook it back up so that the appropriate adds take place.